# Getting intersection between two files in R

Tags: r, intervals, intersect

I have human exon locations ***(chromosome number, start of exon and end of exon)***

```
> head(a1)
        exon Chromosome Start   End
1 uc001aaa.3          1 11873 12227
2 uc001aaa.3          1 12612 12721
3 uc001aaa.3          1 13220 14409
4 uc010nxr.1          1 11873 12227
5 uc010nxr.1          1 12645 12697
6 uc010nxr.1          1 13220 14409
> str(a)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ exon      : chr  "uc001aaa.3" "uc001aaa.3" "uc001aaa.3" "uc010nxr.1" ...
 $ Chromosome: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Start     : int  11873 12612 13220 11873 12645 13220 11873 12594
 $ End       : int  12227 12721 14409 12227 12697 14409 12227 12721
> dput(a)
structure(list(exon = c("uc001aaa.3", "uc001aaa.3", "uc001aaa.3", 
"uc010nxr.1", "uc010nxr.1", "uc010nxr.1", "uc010nxq.1", "uc010nxq.1"
), Chromosome = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Start = c(11873L, 
12612L, 13220L, 11873L, 12645L, 13220L, 11873L, 12594L), End = c(12227L, 
12721L, 14409L, 12227L, 12697L, 14409L, 12227L, 12721L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
>
```

I have another file like

```
  > head(a2)
  SampleID Chromosome    Start      End
1  sampel1          1    64613  5707515
2  sampel1          1  5712940  5732322
3  sampel1          1  5732399 16383682
4  sampel1          1 16383742 16389288
5  sampel1          1 16390813 16830026
6  sampel1          1 16830201 17278112
> str(a2)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ SampleID  : chr  "sampel1" "sampe1" "sampel1" "sampel1" ...
 $ Chromosome: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Start     : int  64613 5712940 5732399 16383742 16390813 16830201 17284498
 $ End       : int  5707515 5732322 16383682 16389288 16830026 17278112 120374803
> dput(a2)
structure(list(SampleID = c("sampel1", "sampe1", "sampel1", "sampel1", 
"sampel1", "sampel1", "sampel1"), Chromosome = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Start = c(64613L, 5712940L, 5732399L, 16383742L, 
16390813L, 16830201L, 17284498L), End = c(5707515L, 5732322L, 
16383682L, 16389288L, 16830026L, 17278112L, 120374803L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
>
```

I want to know how many exon locate in intervals of the second file

Let's say in the second file how many exon are in `64613`   to `5707515`

My desire output is like

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible version of these data. Is the first column in the second row in the second file supposed to be sample1? What is your desired output with these two sample tables?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`GenomicRanges`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
a1.GRanges <- GRanges(a1$Chromosome,
                         ranges = IRanges(a1$Start, a1$End),
                         seqinfo = a1$exons)

a2.GRanges <- GRanges(a2$Chromosome,
                                ranges = IRanges(a2$Start, a2$End),
                                seqinfo = a2$SampleID)

findOverlaps(a2.GRanges,a1.GRanges)
```

As @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 alludes, there are no overlaps in these ranges.

Comment: Do you have any info on how `GRanges` compares with `foverlaps` from "data.table"? That was the other approach I had in mind.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I have not benchmarked `foverlaps`, but I have used `GRanges::findOverlaps` on genome scale data to assess Alu elements. It works very well for anything that will fit in memory, in my case about 100 GB.

Comment: Sorry why I get this error?  > a2.GRanges <- GRanges(a2$Chromosome,
+                       ranges = IRanges(a2$Start, a2$End),
+                       seqinfo = a2$SampleID)
Error in .normarg_seqlevels(seqnames) : 
  supplied 'seqlevels' cannot contain duplicated sequence names
>